# One DFS Replication Group per Namespace

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs, dfs-r

I'm in the process of implementing a single DFS namespace which will be holding approximately 20 or so Folder Targets.

These folders are also going to be replicated to the other servers using DFS-R.

I'm wondering whether I should set up a single replication group for all the shares, or create replication groups for each individual share.

Ideally, I'd like to have the one replication group containing everything.

The problem I'm getting (I'm not sure if it's actually a problem though) is that if I manually create my replication group and add folders into it, the folder does not appear as `Published to Namespace` and it also does not have the replication icon on the folder displayed in the namespace:

[image: FolderLinks]

I believe this is because by doing it this way, somehow the namespace share and the replication are not 'linked'.

Is there any way I can have all my shares and replication items 'linked' to a single replication group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve this.

Firstly, I created the shares in the namespace.

Secondly, In my single replication group I started creating new Replicated Folders.
I pointed the replicated folder to the root folder of my share on the drive of each server.

After creating a standalone Target in the Namespace, and a standalone Replicated Folder, I could then link them together by right clicking on my Replicated Folder under the Replication section, choose share and publish to Namespace (it actually auto-detected the shares for me on both servers at this stage).

At this point, the Replicated Folder and Target Folder were linked as if I had done it the reverse way around.